# Raspberry pi 4 USB 3 ports not working

Tags: raspbian, usb, hard-drive, usb3

i experienced some serious problems with my Raspberry Pi 4 regarding my USB 3.0 ports.
I was using the raspberry as a server (torrents, ftps, http etc...).
To store the data i opted for a 1Tb usb hdd i had laying around, I plugged it in and it worked absolutely fine for months, one day i noticed that i wasn't able to access my ftps cliend so i connected to ssh to check the problem.
I noticed that the hdd was somehow disconnected (not recognized, i tried using lsusb to check but it was undetected).
I started searching through logs when i started to see some particular lines in dmesg

`device descriptor read/64, error -110`

`device descriptor read/64, error -71`

I tried everything, from buying a powered usb cable to add config to modprobe to make usbcore use the old linux usb schema, i formatted the sd and put a new copy of raspberry pi os.
I tested with other usb devices, the hdd works flawlessly with other computers.
I also tried to connect a small 8 Gb usb stick to the raspberry to see if the problem was of the hdd but the raspberry didn't recognize the stick too.
Basically when i connect the hdd to the raspberry the led of the hdd powers up for 3 to 10 seconds then it goes dark again.
The only way to make it work is to use the USB 2.0 ports, but it's a temporary arrangement since i want to install a usb sdd to the raspberry instead of the sd.

I hope to resolve this problem soon, so thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What OS are you running on your RPi 4?

Comment: @Sanders: note the OP's statement, "`i formatted the sd and put a new copy of raspberry pi os.`"

Comment: A little more information might help. Run `lsusb -t`, & add the output to your question. You might also run `sudo lsusb -v` & peruse the output (probably not useful to post all output). IIRC, `eth0` and the USB3 share some hardware, so it might be useful to verify whether or not your RPi4 can connect to your network via ethernet cable.

Comment: I overlooked what OS you're running, I can be blind.  Anything in `dmesg | grep usb` by chance as well?